# Wildcard Cloudflare and trusted certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare, wildcard

I would like use my website in ssl only but with cloudflare all my subdomain are not trusted (i think because is not in "cloudflare" DNS ( record by orange clouding)).

If i add manually subdomain example "test.website.com" with orange clouding the SSL work correctly.

I have ordered a Edge Certificates but is not resolve my problem.

How can i make SSL with wildcard on all subdomain without Cloudflare DNS (orange clouding) ?

(I have tryied SSL "Flexible" and "Strict", i have added certificate on my nginx and currently i use "Strict" SSL)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Cloudflare allows you to input [wildcard DNS records](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168826-Does-CloudFlare-support-wildcard-DNS-entries-) on any plan, only Enterprise customers can actually proxy those records through Cloudflare.

Instead; to get protection on those subdomains, just enter in the DNS record itself into the Cloudflare DNS settings and ensure the record is orange-clouded.

Note that Cloudflare's SSL only applies to a single subdomain and [not sub-subdomains](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/219453397-Can-I-use-CloudFlare-SSL-certificates-on-my-fourth-level-subdomain-); so whilst `dev.example.com` would be covered, `www.dev.example.com` would not. In order to do this, you would need to use [Cloudflare's Dedicated Certificates offering](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/228009108-Dedicated-SSL-Certificates).

Comment: Thanks, i have already buyed a Edge certificate. I have tested with the api to record subdomain when is added on my website but the delay for activation on browser is too slow.^^. PS : i don't want wildcard in cloudflare (orange-clouded), just secure with SSL all subdomain ^^.